# SQL. How to insert data into two tables at a time when one related to another with a foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

I have two tables:

`Attr.type_id` is a foreign key to `Type.id`

[image]

Let's assume I want to save the following data:

```
{
  name: 'cats',
  attributes: ['breed', 'weight']
}
```

I expect this after saving:

[image]

How do I properly write an insert query?

I know I can't insert into two tables at the same time. Should I use transactions? Or maybe there is a simple way because this seem trivial but in fact it's not.

If you know how to do that using TypeORM, it will be grateful as well

Update: I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: Insert in the `type` table, then insert in the `attr` table... in that order. Using transactions ensures both inserts are done atomically, but it's not clear you need that from your question.

Comment: @TheImpaler No, I don't There's nothing critical. I just really don't want to make two requests

Comment: Those are two SQL statements. If you want a single request you may write a stored procedure, but that's a hassle. Just do two SQL requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As type table is the master table having primary key insert the id first then insert in the attr table. In this order constraint integrity would be mantained as foreign key always refers its parent table for a particular attribute. Hence in your case id is the one which needs to be referred in the type table and then insert in the attr table.